# How function calls with parameters work in C?

Tags: c, function, return-value, function-parameter

I am learning C and came across something I was curious about. For me, calling foo in main like follows does not return anything:

```
int foo(bar){
    return bar * 2;
}

int main(){
    foo(10);
}
```

Only when I format the output with printf will it return the result from foo to main. Is this intended or am I missing something? The following example works:

```
int foo(bar){
    return bar * 2;
}

int main(){
    // will return 20
    printf("%d\n", foo(10));
}
```

Comment: In the first example, you have ignored the return value from `foo()`. You don't *have* to use it, but in this case it is pointless calling the function if you ignore its result. In the second example, you pass its return value to `printf()`.

Comment: Could you dumb it down a bit for me? I am very new to programming in general. What do you mean by I have ignored the return value in the first example? I am currently under the impression that the 'bar' variable being returned within 'foo()' would be passed into the parameters of the function. Is that not it?

Comment: Well, you say `foo()` does not return a value, but it does. You can obtain and report that value with, say, `int retval = foo(10); printf("%d\n", retval);` It's the second example which is more tricky, as you never see the return value, but are feeding it directly into `printf`.

Comment: Your function `foo()` returns a value. You need to 'catch' that value in either a variable (another integer) or through a function (as you did using `printf()`). In your first example you did nothing with the return variable of `foo()`' .

Comment: All great answers, I understand now. Thanks!

Comment: Accept the answer below (see the checkmark).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function call foo(10) in

```c
    int foo(bar){
        return bar * 2;
    }

    int main(){
        foo(10);
    }
```

indeed returns the value. But you were not capturing it in any variable or printing the returned value. Your second example actually prints the value returned from `foo(10);`

Comment: I think I understand it now. So the function is correctly returning the value, but since there is no variable being used to store the return value or a printf statement to print the return, it never shows up when the program executes?

Answer (score 0):

There's already a useful answer, so here is a more-technical answer:

In your second example, you *print*ed the result of `foo(10)`, but there is a way to really *return* a value from a C program.

```
int main() {
    return 14;
}
```

Immediately after running the script in the shell, `echo $?` (or `echo %errorlevel%` on Windows) will print the exit code of the program, which for a simple C program, is the value returned by `main`.

Usually, a value of 0 represents success, and anything else indicates some error or another. The other common way to generate an exit code is by passing an integer (or the constants `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE`) to the `exit` function from `stdlib.h`.

(Of course, you usually want to print the results of your program, or write them to a file, so they are easy to look at or save for later, but it's the type of distinction that might be useful to know about, even if it doesn't come up as often.)